# JList in JScrollPane messes up JPanel height

Tags: height, jpanel, jscrollpane, jlist, border-layout

I have a weird problem that I can't seem to solve. I've got a `JList` which has to be able to scroll if there are more items in it then can be displayed. However if I put the `JList` in a `JScrollPane`, it doesn't utilise the full height of the `EAST` part of the `BorderLayout` it's in.

Example without `JScrollPane`:

```
public UsersPanel(){
    String[] userList = new String[]{"Foo","Bar","Foo","Bar","Foo","Bar","Foo","Bar","Foo","Bar","Foo","Bar","Foo","Bar"};
    JList users = new JList(userList);
    add(users);
}
```

[image: Example without JScrollPane]

Example with `JScrollPane`:

```
public UsersPanel(){
    String[] userList = new String[]{"Foo","Bar","Foo","Bar","Foo","Bar","Foo","Bar","Foo","Bar","Foo","Bar","Foo","Bar"};
    JList users = new JList(userList);

    JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(users);

    add(sp);
}
```

[image: Example with JScrollPane]

I want a `JList` that utilises the full available height of the EAST part of the `BorderLayout` it's in. I've tried wrapping my `JList` inside another `JPanel`, but that doesn't solve my problem either.

Answer (score 1):

use setVisibleRowCount() method to set number of visible rows in Jlist.
    users.setVisibleRowCount(10);

Answer (score 0):

One hack that I've used successfully before is to add a ComponentListener to parent component of the JList / JScrollPane, and as it changes reset the preferred size of the JList and/or Jscrollpane via (pseudo-code) setPreferredSize(getPreferredSize().width, parentHeight)